# Clear all messages that are not images or links by using discord.js and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I have a bot in discord in JavaScript and I need to start a timer in 24 hours and clear all messages in a certain channel if they are not pictures or links, since I do not know how timers work here and how to distinguish messages with text from messages with pictures, please help (please do not write a ready-made script, but at least explain how it all works :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a message contains an image you can check the Collection `<Message>.attachments.first()`, this will return falsey if no image was attached.

```
const image = <Message>.attachments.first();
if (!image) <Message>.delete();
```

*One way* to check for a link is to see if `<Message>.content` starts with `'http'`

```
const hasLink = <Message>.content.startsWith('http');
if (!hasLink) <Message>.delete();
```

However it's pretty easy to bypass this. You may want to check out [Regular Expressions (Regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

`<Message>` is a placeholder for your message object.

Comment: Unfortunately, messages do not have to *start* with http. It can include it in the middle.

Comment: That's why I included "*One way* to check for a link...". It's also assumed that the content of the message is just a link based off the wording from the OP's post. Otherwise yes they can be anywhere in the string

Comment: that's good, but how to start the timer?

Comment: You could have a boolean that decides whether the messages should be deleted or not. Have a [setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/#when-i-say-so-execution-settimeout) function change the boolean's value after 24h in ms

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```js
if(!message.attachments.first() && !message.content.match(/https?:\/\/.+/)) message.delete();
```

The regex expression looks for `"http"`, and the optional `"s"`, along with the rest of the link. I do not believe there is something to look if it is a link itself.